# Calling a javascript function on a php variable

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript:

```
function capitalizeFL(string) { 
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

PHP:

```
echo "You have chosen a <script>document.write(capitalizeFL(".$race."));</script>";
```

`$race` contains a string. What I would like is simply to capitalize the first letter of the php variable `$race`, using the Javascript function above, and print it on the page.

I could find another way of doing this, but this JS-PHP mixing thing is confusing to me and I'd very much like to figure out WHY this doesn't work.

Comment: `capitalizeFL(my string)` needs to be `capitalizeFL('my string')` so you need to delimit $race with `'` to identify it as a string and escape any `'` within the text too. e.g. your string could be `O'Neil`

Comment: Why not just use a PHP function to do this. Take a look at the following functions: - [string strtoupper(string $string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) Except ofcourse there's a specific reason why you are using a javascript function there.

Comment: @Bernard as I've mentioned in my question I could find other ways of doing it, just wanted to understand for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the generated JavaScript.

```
document.write(capitalizeFL(value_of_race));
```

That's an identifier, not a string literal. You need to include quote marks in your generated JS.

Given a string, the `json_encode` function will output the equivalent JS literal (even if it isn't valid JSON). Use that to convert your PHP variables into JS literals.

```
$js_race = json_encode($race);
echo "You have chosen a <script>document.write(capitalizeFL($js_race));</script>";
```

Comment: ie. document.write(capitalizeFL('".$race."'));

Comment: @Jace — That will break if the string contains `'` characters.

Comment: @Waygood — Yes, but Jace's code doesn't do that (and your comment doesn't provide any code to do the escaping). Mine does (although it uses `"` instead of `'`).

Comment: I don't understand one thing. $race IS a string. Say it contains "human". Then wouldn't value_of_race be "human", already with quotes, rather than just human?

Comment: No. Quote marks delimit the start and end of a string literal (in both PHP and JavaScript). They aren't *part* of the string, they just contain it. If they were, then you would have `"` characters showing up every time you tried to print anything in PHP, which would be awful.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "You have chosen a <script>document.write(capitalizeFL('".$race."'));</script>";
```

You can try above code.
Javascript string must be wrapped by ''.